# Can I create an angular component that doesn't render given a certain condition?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a debugging component which is very simple and looks like this.

debug.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="debugging">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-container>



export class DebugComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.debugging =  environment.debugging;
  }

  debugging: boolean;


}
```

I use it like this

```
 <app-debug>{{data | json}}</app-debug>
```

I have an environment variable that I can turn on and off if I want to see the debugging data or not.

```
export const environment = {
...
  debugging: false,
...
}
```

However, I notice that when I render my page, even when I have debugging = false, in my rendered HTML, I still see lines like this

```
<app-debug _ngcontent-ydq-c8="" _nghost-ydq-c16=""><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></app-debug>
```

It's invisible but if possible, I don't really want my debugging code being deployed to prod.

Is it possible to create a component that doesn't render given a certain condition?

Answer (score 4):

You could remove the debug component host "by hand" with standard DOM methods. Here is one way to do it with `ElementRef` and `removeChild`:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-debug",
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class DebugComponent implements OnInit {
  debugging: boolean;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.debugging =  environment.debugging;
    if (!this.debugging) {
      let element = this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
      element.parentElement.removeChild(element);
    }
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ifj3jd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdebug.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: Is it worth the trouble? Naturally question arises as to which approach has the least performance impact. Is it better to leave the element in the DOM or to remove it?

Comment: I understand... although to be honest, it'd be pointless for my use case to do this. I may as well just use the ng-container option that Michael D suggested. Not only do I have to still import environment into the parent components, I'd have to keep track of all my debug statements and delete them. Although maybe, if I could do it on a "module" level, it might be worth it...

Comment: @Diskdrive - You don't have to import the environment in the parent component. Why do you think you have to do it? Everything is done in the debug component, as you asked. The `*ngIf` is simply replaced with DOM code, which allows to remove the host element.

Comment: @ConnorsFan - oh actually I've just realized I misread your code. Yeah you're right! Okay, yeah I think that would work! Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelD - you do raise a good point - normally, in a traditional non-SPA app, generating less HTML means less network traffic, but this is all generated client side. Maybe I'm overthinking this, and having the debug code in the html isn't really that bad

Answer (score 2):

how about a structural directive instead of a component...

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[appDebug]"
})
export class DebugDirective {
   constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {
     if (environment.debugging) {
       this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
     }
   }
}
```

which you should be able to just toss where ever it's needed...

```
<ng-container *appDebug>{{data | json}}</ng-container>
```

this is higher performance than a component in production as it will just never render and you will not need to remove it from the DOM. It will also work the same on any element, not just an `ng-container`

blitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rzzgsy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

the only artifact from this method will be some html comment like:

```
<!--container-->
```

Answer (score 1):

The child component isn't wrapped in the condition. To completely disable the rendering of a component, the condition should be applied to the it's selector.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="debugging">
  <app-debug>{{data | json}}</app-debug>
</ng-container>
```

or

```html
<app-debug *ngIf="debugging">{{data | json}}</app-debug>
```

Comment: yeah that would work, and that's what I had initially. But I figured I'm repeating that for every single line i want to debug which is why I wanted to put it inside a component

Comment: Why not apply the condition directly to the `app-debug` element?

Comment: @ConnorsFan: Would be fewer LOC yes, but I am thinking about working around the overhead of importing the `environment` variable in every single component.